# How To run react native application in ios without dev options and shake device or without packager?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, react-native-ios, xcode10

I already followed these document ,but still its not working.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

and also first time application freeze and stuck ,user can not actions on screen.

I have Login Screen ,
after login screen there is home screen.
when i came home screen after login. 
First time application freeze and not happens any actions,but when remove application from recent then open application its working fine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [ask] and [mcve] as this is likely a code or configuration issue, we'll need to see the relevant code/config to help.

Comment: If you want to run the application without packager then you have to install the .ipa file on the iphone

Answer (score 1):

Open XCode and go to **Product** -> **Scheme** -> **Edit Scheme**. Select Run tab and set the Build Configuration to Release. Shake menu and packager are only accesible in debug mode.

Afterwards you can build via XCode or with the command **react-native run-ios --configuration Release**

Read the official [RN documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) for further information.